# How to deal with backyard flooding?

Tags: outdoor, drainage, flooding

So I am finally tired of walking through puddles to get to my garage. I am doing research to find out the best way to deal with my backyard flooding problem. I am in a townhouse with a small backyard that runs to my detached garage and it floods on heavy rains. I have attached some images of the issue and the yard. As you can see it has a slope from the house to the garage and a low spot that collect all the water.

[image]

I am looking at the best simple options I can do myself to fix the issue. Would regrading the slop and low spot fix the issue? or do I need to do some sort of french drainage? I dont really see a great place to run the drainage since it either goes to the garage or the edge of the fenced yard into others.

Ideally I am thinking of redoing the backyard in some sort of AstroTurf, would using dirt or pebbles to grade then laying over it with astro turf work?

Comment: Welcome. You'd have to tell us a bit about the average slope in that area and what's around it. It's hard to suggest solutions with so little information.

Comment: With this being a townhome, isn't your HOA responsible for this?

Comment: I would say it is a 10-15* degree slop to the garage but the yard itself drips then evens out. HOA wont cover it.

Comment: @qwerty  10-degree is a pretty steep slope.  I doubt it's that much --  use some string and a level to make a "triangle" measurement..

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Your tright, I did some math and it is closer to 3.5-4* thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints, I'd remove the walkway stones, lower either side slightly (and probably bury a perforated pipe, or several to connect them and speed drainage) raise the walkway (possibly just using soil removed from either side), and reset the stones.

Beware of buried utilities - The official ones 811 (or your local call before you dig option if it's not 811) will mark for you, and the ones they won't know about such as wiring between your house and garage. They *should* be below the extent I'd expect to dig for this (less than a foot) but always check, and aways be wary (smooth black roots are not roots!)

Comment: But the water still has to go *somewhere* .   This has all the hallmarks of a cheap-ass developer.   Raising the walkway will keep the stones drier but look how low the door into the garage is.  OP may have to consider cutting a sump hole inside the garage and draining down the driveway or some such.